# Does GWT have a widget which represent <span> HTML tag

Tags: gwt

I know that `Flowpanel` in GWT will be compiled into `div` and `Horizontal/Vertical Panel` will be compiled to `table`. Is there any widget available to represent `span` in GWT ?

Or

Is there a way to achieve it apart from **GWT - `HTML` widget** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SpanElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/SpanElement.html) you can achieve this.

```
Element div = DOM.createDiv();

Element spanElement = DOM.createSpan();
DOM.appendChild(div, SpanElement.as(spanElement));
```

Answer (score 1):

`InlineLabel` or `InlineHTML` would be what you're looking for; or use HTML markup in UiBinder within a `HTMLPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a HTML `<span>` container then [SpanElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/SpanElement.html) is a way to go.

But, if you want a **widget** (with all its features) that is rendered as a `<span>` element you want something else.

Take a look at the [SimplePanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html) constructors:

> `public SimplePanel()`
>
> Creates an empty panel that uses a DIV for its contents.

and

> `protected SimplePanel(Element elem)`
>
> Creates an empty panel that uses the specified browser element for its contents.

Now you look at the implementation of the first constructor:

```
public SimplePanel() {
    this(DOM.createDiv());
}
```

So, you just want to replace it with `DOM.createSpan()`.

This constructor is `protected` so you need to extend SimplePanel:

```
public class SpanPanel extends SimplePanel {
    public SpanPanel() {
        super(DOM.createSpan());
    }
}
```